# C program redirect to a file

Tags: c, io-redirection

I have the following code and if I try to redirect it to a file, no prompts are output. It redirects both the prompt and the resultant output to my file.

Is there a way to have it output prompts to stdout and then the output to the file?

```
/*prints chars in rows and columns*/
#include <stdio.h>

void display(char cr, int lines, int width); /*prototypes are fun*/

int main(void) {
    int ch; /*char to be printed*/
    int rows, cols; /*number of rows and columns*/
    printf("Enter a character and two integers.\n");

    while((ch = getchar()) != '\n') {
        if(scanf("%d %d", &rows, &cols) != 2) {
            break;
        }
        display(ch, rows, cols);
        while(getchar() != '\n') {
            continue;
        }
        printf("Enter another character and two integers. Newline quits.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}

void display(char cr, int lines, int width) {
    int row, col;
    for(row = 1; row <= lines; row++) {
        for(col = 1; col <= width; col++) {
            putchar(cr);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

Comment: When you redirect, the file *is* stdout.  So anything you print to stdout will end up in the file.  If you want to print to the tty, try printing to stderr (and don't redirect stderr).

Comment: What's the OS? You might find it easier to do this by piping to the `tee` command.

Comment: How do I use `tee`?   `program | tee > outfile` does not work nor does `program | tee outfile`

Comment: Using `tee` won't solve your problem, because it won't send part of the output to the file and part to stdout. Use William's idea of printing the prompts to stderr, or my answer below printing the other output to a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to make the filename an (optional) command-line argument.

To do this, you would change the beginning of your `main` like:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  FILE* outfile;
  if (argc == 2) outfile = fopen(argv[1], "w");
  else outfile = stdout;
```

(To be safe, you should probably check that `outfile` is not null in case there is an error opening the file. You might also want to check for improper number of command-line arguments, make a help message, and so on, depending on who this program is for.)

Then you have to pass this `FILE*` to the `display` function, which requires changing that function signature like

```
void display(char cr, int lines, int width, FILE* outfile) {
```

And finally, change your `putchar` calls to `putc` so you can send them to the file, like

```
putc('\n', outfile);
```

After all this, running your program like

```
./myprog
```

will print all prompts as well as the output to stdout, whereas running it with a filename like

```
./myprog file.txt
```

will still print the prompts to stdout, but the other output will go to `file.txt`.

Comment: This is interesting as I have barely touched on programming FILE I/O in C.

What is the `FILE *outfile` part? I have seen it before, but is FILE a special data type or what?

Comment: `FILE` is defined in `stdio.h` and it holds information on reading or writing to any file-like thing (could be a device, a terminal, or an actual file). You might want to read a tutorial on C I/O like [this one](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/cfileio.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the link to the tutorial

Answer (score 0):

While dealing with redirect output to a file you may use [freopen()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/freopen/).

Though it's not a good solution, but it is a good example how to use `freopen()`. Assuming you are trying to redirect your `stdout` to a file **'output.txt'** then you can write -

```
freopen("output.txt", "a+", stdout);
```

Here **"a+"** for append mode. If the file exists then the file open in append mode. Otherwise a new file is created.

After reopening the `stdout` with `freopen()` all output statement (`printf`, `putchar`) are redirected to the  **'output.txt'**. So when you try to redirect the `'printf("Enter another character and two integers. Newline quits.\n");'`statement again in terminal/command prompt then you have to reassign `stdout` again using the following code-

```
freopen("/dev/tty", "w", stdout); /*for gcc, ubuntu*/
```

or

```
freopen("CON", "w", stdout); /*Mingw C++; Windows*/
```

Here is the full code -

```
/*prints chars in rows and columns*/
#include <stdio.h>

void display(char cr, int lines, int width); /*prototypes are fun*/

int main(void) {
    int ch; /*char to be printed*/
    int rows, cols; /*number of rows and columns*/

    printf("Enter a character and two integersk.\n");

    while((ch = getchar()) != '\n') {
        if(scanf("%d %d", &rows, &cols) != 2) {
            break;
        }

        freopen("output.txt", "a+", stdout);
        display(ch, rows, cols);
        freopen("/dev/tty", "w", stdout); /*for gcc, ubuntu*/
        //freopen("CON", "w", stdout); /*Mingw C++; Windows*/

        printf("Enter another character and two integers. Newline quits.\n");
        while(getchar() != '\n') {
            continue;
        }
        fclose(stdout);
    }

    return 0;
}

void display(char cr, int lines, int width) {
    int row, col;

    for(row = 1; row <= lines; row++) {
        for(col = 1; col <= width; col++) {
            putchar(cr);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
    return;
}
```

Thanks